# Installation of mysql server causes akonadi server to fail on Kubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: kde, akonadi

I am experiencing the exact same situation as described in this query [KMail stops working after install of MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301288/kmail-stops-working-after-install-of-mysql) I have not seen a resolution anywhere. Does this mean that the only way forward is to move up to Ubuntu 21.04?

I uninstalled the new mysql server and reinstalled akonadi-server and akonadi-backend-mysql. Did not help. Is there a known issue with akonadi on Ubuntu 20.04.2?

Answer (score 0):

To be helpful to anyone who might need help with this situation, I provide below the steps that I took to resolve the situation.
I found this [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1953675) very helpful.

1. I upgraded to Kubuntu 20.10 using the command:
   sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
2. I renamed the ib log files in ~/.local/share/akonadi/db_data,
3. I set innodb_force_recovery=1 in .local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf
4. I started MariaDB through using command: akonadictl start
5. I ran: mysql_upgrade --socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket
6. I shut down Akonadi server using akonadictl stop.
7. I rebooted.
   Everything worked after this. Akonadi server started normally and so I could use my Kontact tools.